# Connect to Google Services from Apps gives blank dialog

Tags: google-drive

Recently (last couple of months) whenever I try to link an App (on my phone) to my Google account I simply get a blank dialog.

I have reached out to Google via the phone help system and I've ended up here.

It is not limited to a device — happens on another phone and tablet.  Factory reset does not help either.  It is also a specific account — I tried a new test account and that works without issue.

I've probably set a setting somewhere which limits something, but would appreciate any help with this?

An example would be using the Tasker app to try to backup my profiles to Google drive — it has to ask for permission, but the dialog is blank.

Please help?

Thanks in advance,

-- Peter.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it is this issue:

[Sign in issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141436960)

So a switch of my account from @googlemail.com to @gmail.com has fixed it.